# How to add multiple CSS classes to an single array

Tags: html, css, arrays, perl

Here is the partial script, I am printing table from Oracle DB in HTML to an email, which contains 3 columns; for the 3rd column there are only two values: `PASS` or `FAIL`. If the cell has `PASS`, the `bgcolor` of the cell will be `green`, and if it is `FAIL`, I want `bgcolor` to be `RED`.

Below code works, but I am not sure how to add another class (`red`) if the condition is `FAIL`.

```
  chomp($ary[2]);
  push(@HTML,sprintf("<td%s>%s</td>",
                (($ary[2]) eq "PASS")? " class=\"green\"" : "",
                $ary[2]));
```

Comment: Do the values coming out of the database really have newlines on them? That seems... odd.

Comment: Look at http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch03_16.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just finish the ternary condition with something other than an empty string:

```
push(@HTML, sprintf('<td class="%s">%s</td>', ($ary[2] eq 'PASS' ? 'green' : 'red'), $ary[2]));
```

Although, do you really need `sprintf` when simple string interpolation will do? This produces arguably more readable code:

```
my $class = $ary[2] eq 'PASS' ? 'green' : 'red';
push(@HTML, "<td class='$class'>$ary[2]</td>");
```

---

Edit: answer to your second question below. I'd use a simple conditional rather than multiple levels of ternary operators because I find it infinitely more readable.

```
my $class;

if ($ary[2] eq 'PASS') {
    $class = 'green';
} elsif ($ary[2] eq 'FAIL') {
    $class = 'red';
} else {
    $class = 'yellow';
}

push(@HTML, "<td class='$class'>$ary[2]</td>");
```

Comment: If this solution answers your question, you should mark it as the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Matt, if i had more than 2 conditions how to use the conditional operator. Say if i had values other than PASS or FAIL , i should get yellow. Please through some light...

Comment: tried below it worked like a charm    (($ary[2] eq 'PASS' )? 'green' : ($ary[2] eq 'FAIL') ?  'red') : 'yellow',$ary[2]));

Comment: While you certainly _can_ nest ternary operators, I try to avoid it for the sake of readability. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks Matt.  By nesting ternary operators i can able to get the result. Thanks again for the quick help!!

Comment: Well, I guess that settles it, then. Nest away until your program is one giant ternary decision tree!